# Ruby regex to replace character sequence

Tags: regex, ruby

So I have this string

```
x = "{"1"=>"test","2"=>"Another=>Test","3"=>"Another=>One"}"
```

and I want to replace the **rocket symbol that is beside a character** to a pipe symbol. so the result is

```
x = "{"1"=>"test","2"=>"Another|Test","3"=>"Another|One"}"
```

I have this code right now

```
if x =~ /(=>\w)/).present?
    x.match(/=>\w/) do |match|
      #loop through matches and replace => with |
    end
end
```

So basically my question is how do I loop through a matched by regex and replace the rocket sign to a pipe?

Comment: That string looks like the string representation of a Ruby hash. Where do you get the string from? I did you consider working on the original Ruby hash?

Comment: `gsub` will let you replace parts of string by regex

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes but I dont want to replace =>T to | I just wanted to replace => to a | if it matches the regex /=>\w/

Comment: @stuckoverflow24: ah, I see. In this case, you could use a positive lookahead (assert presence without including it in the match). Look it up.

Comment: If this was a Ruby structure instead of a string representation of a Ruby structure, or even JSON, this would be trivial with `transform_values`. Instead you've got yourself in a jam here where you need to do some heavy parsing. The example you've given is not valid Ruby code, mind you, those inner quotes *must* be escaped if this is actually a string and not just a Ruby hash.

Comment: @tadman this is from an old data that I want to fix. Yes those quotes are escaped but I removed them so it will be readable

Comment: I'm specifically asking for the code in your question to match, exactly, what you're trying to deal with. Right now that's not valid Ruby code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` with a [positive look-ahead](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) will do it.

```
x = %q[{"1"=>"test","2"=>"Another=>Test","3"=>"Another=>One"}]
x.gsub!(%r{=>(?=\w)}, '|')
puts x
```

A look-ahead (or look-behind) matches, but does not include that bit in the match.

Though I think `%r{=>(?=[^"])}`, a `=>` which is not in front of a quote, is more correct.

```
x = %q[{"1"=>"what about => a space?","2"=>"Or=>(this)"}]
x.gsub!(%r{=>(?=[^"])}, '|')
puts x
```